# Tagger 4.0.0 and EE 3.2.1 - Error when trying to create a Tag Group

Tags: devdemon, ee3, devdemon-tagger, tagger, compatibility

When you try and create a tag group in DevDemon's Tagger 4.0 addon, it doesn't work. When you click 'Save Group' it throws the following:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function hasModule() on a non-object in /system/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Addons/Addons.php on line 1106
```

Looking at that file we have:

```
private function getModule($name)
    {
        try
        {
            $info = ee('Addon')->get($name);
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            show_404();
        }
        if ( ! $info->hasModule())
        {
            return array();
        }
```

Any thoughts? Is Tagger not EE 3.1.x compatible? Anyone know or have any thoughts?

Comment: I can't publish comment so I publish an answer that isn't it, sorry. Tagger 4.0.0 still has the issue. It is possible to create new groups only if the CP session type is set to 'Cookies only'. But anyway there's no possibilities to create tags (there is no 'NEW' button anywhere) when you have created a group. And no way to delete a group, I got this when I try to : Exception Caught
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'myDBname.exp_tagger_tags' doesn't exist:
SELECT tagger_m_Tag_tagger_tags.tag_id as tagger_m_Tag__tag_id, tagger_m_Tag_tagger_tags.tag_name as tagger_m_Tag__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest version of Tagger. The issue was due incorrect URL generation if CP Session ID and Cookies where used.

Comment: Tagger 4.0.0 on EE 3.3.3 has the same issue. I don't see the fix.

Comment: DevDemon abandoned their post. Luckily they sold everything to VectorMedia in NYC who will be keeping the add-ons alive and supported. I'm sure this one will get this addressed properly, however, there are higher priority add-ons they will address first.